# ACF: Echo page title when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, pages

How can I show the title when a checkbox is checked. I use Advanced custom fields

my field name is nav

This is what i currently have.

```
<?php if(get_field('nav')) { ?> 
   <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="active"><?php the_title();?></a>

</li> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: and the `nav` field returns exactly what? what type of field is it..? please try `var_dump(get_field('nav'));`

Comment: Hi @honk31, The field type is checkbox. Atm nav returns nothing. What i have is a  checkbox that shows on every page. And what im trying to do is if that checkbox is checked echo the pages title. Would u know how?

Comment: if you only use the field for the title, consider to change it from checkbox to true/false. it will still be a checkbox, but will return true if checked and false if not. or post your setting for the select field and we check, whats wrong there..

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code? I am interested in the context, where exactly do you call for `the_title()`, and why is it in a `li` element? Are there multiple titles?

Comment: After looking at your code I would say it should already work the way you want. The if condition evaluates to true and the title is displayd, if it gets a `truthy` (i.e. the checkbox is checked in a page edit screen) value. Otherwise the condition is `false`and the title would not be displayed. What does `var_dump(get_field('nav'));` give you if you have the checkbox checked in a page edit screen?

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use ACF true/false field > [link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/)

Then basically in your template wrap the title element in conditional, like this:

```
if( get_field( 'title_show_or_whatever' ) ) {
    // The title element
}
```

Comment: Thanks dboris, What I have tried is :    <?php if(get_field('nav'')) { ?>
        <li>
          <a  href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="active"><?php the_title();?></a>
        </li>
     <?php  } ?>  But this doesn't work

Comment: my field name is nav

Comment: @Gago You have a typo in your code, in `get_field('nav'')`, ending string with two single quotes. Consider enabling [WP Debug](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) in your `wp-config.php` file: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: I miss typed. I added code in my original question. I have done it your way but get nothing when i try to get title. My goal is when check box is checked echo that page's title. Please if u could help

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try php [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for your if statement.

```
<?php if (get_field('nav')): ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" class="active">
        <?php the_title();?> 
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```